# max of two columns wrt to one another

Tags: r, dplyr

dataset of multiple blood pressures per patient_ID. Trying to find the max measurement per patient.

dataset looks something like where each row is a separate observation (bp measurement):

```
data.frame(
      patient_ID = c('1','1','1','2','2','2'),
       bp_systolic = c(80, 85, 72, 95, 90, 75),
      bp_diastolic = c(120, 133, 100, 140, 130, 120)
   )
```

and ideally I would like the final product to look like this:

| patient_ID | highest_systolic | highest_diastolic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85 | 133 |
| 2 | 95 | 140 |

I want to preserve the 2 groupings of blood pressure together. So not just selecting the higest systolic out of the 3 systolic measurements per patient ID but selecting it wrt the highest diastolic. Since each row is a unique measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want, for each patient, the row where the highest diastolic measurement occurs?

```
df %>% group_by(patient_ID) %>% slice_max(bp_diastolic)
```

OR:

```
slice_max(df,bp_diastolic,by=patient_ID)
```

Output:

```
  patient_ID bp_systolic bp_diastolic
  <chr>            <dbl>        <dbl>
1 1                   85          133
2 2                   95          140
```

Comment: is it possible to use slice_max in an if_else() ?

Comment: possibly.. i think it depends on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In base R use:

```
aggregate(.~patient_ID, df, max)

  patient_ID bp_systolic bp_diastolic
1          1          85          133
2          2          95          140
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, this is not quite right. i believe the op wants the measurement pairs to remain together. given the small dataset provided, the example outcome is the same either way, but might not be correct on a larger dataset

Comment: @langtang I get your point. Well seems all the solutions here would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fmax`

```
library(collapse)
 fmax(df1[-1], g = df1$patient_ID)
  bp_systolic bp_diastolic
1          85          133
2          95          140
```